# With TableLayout margin, TableRows bleed

Tags: android, layout

I'm creating a Settings screen, a ScrollView with a TableLayout inside. I don't want my settings TableRows to appear squished, so I'm setting each with an 8dp margin. However, this means the content inside seems to bleed over (on the right side in particular).

It seems as if the width of the table row does not exclude its own margin's width, which is messing up the width of its contents when they try to fill_parent for their own width. How do I fix this?

An image example - see the checkboxes on the right side:
[image: screenshot of android emulator]

My layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settings">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0">

            <TableRow android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_padding">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Settings"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_margin="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/row_height">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="No margin"
                        android:id="@+id/textView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="Explanation"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_margin="@dimen/row_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="8dp margin"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:checked="false" />
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting margin directly on the `TableRow` tag you can add margin on the contents i.e table cells,

I have modified your code. Please have a look at.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/settings">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0">

        <TableRow >
            <TextView
                android:text="Settings"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_margin="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="No margin"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Explanation"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="8dp margin"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:checked="false" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope It will help you!

Comment: Thanks, that solution works. Is the behaviour I describe expected? Seems a little unusual to me.